# Too much leavener in self-rasing flour?

Tags: leavening

I made scones with this recipe today: http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/recipes/scones_1285

And I followed it very thoroughly (weighing all the ingredients in grams, etc). They came out looking great with a nice rise, but they had a 'base'y flavor to them that surprised me, almost as if too much leavener had been used. But since the recipe calls for self-raising flour, I didn't add any at all.

So either:

- I'm very sensitive to basey  flavors (which is possible, I'm pregnant and sensitive to all things right now)
- The scones are supposed to taste like this (the commercial scones I've had before haven't)
- There was something wrong with my flour.

I don't generally use self raising flour for baking, so I'm not sure about its leavener content. Do self rasisng flours usually contain enough to taste it in the baking?

Comment: Was your flour fresh?

Comment: Yes it was. I bought it this week.

Answer (score 1):

Self-raising flour shouldn't leave any off flavors, and the recipe looks fine. I suspect the flour, maybe you got a bag that got too much leavening agent in it. Manufacturing processes aren't perfect, sometimes the agents are not distributed. I would suggest trying again with a new bag of flour.